# how can I reintegrate a lost and found pv into an LVM vg?

Tags: linux, raid, lvm, partition-recovery

I recently lost a RAID that was a physical volume of one of my linux LVM volume groups.  I ended up doing a `vgreduce --removemissing` and got on with the business of restoring the data.

Well, today I found that RAID (it was hiding, don't ask).

```
# pvdisplay -m /dev/md2
  WARNING: Volume group mg20 is not consistent
  "/dev/md2" is a new physical volume of "499.87 GiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md2
  VG Name               
  PV Size               499.87 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0   
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               SUXIe9-B4xG-Qlbz-5cSd-f1dh-cRQh-vOF4qz
```

`mg20` is not consistent because the lost&found PV `/dev/md2` probably contains copies of the old logical volume catalog that mentions the filesystem living on `/dev/md2`.

How do I reintegrate `/dev/md2` into `mg20` and preserve the filesystem that lives on it? (and save myself the hassle of restoring its contents)  A simplifying factor is that `/dev/md2` contained only one LV and that LV was entirely contained on `/dev/md2`.

Comment: I found some useful info at http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2007-November/msg00040.html http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2007-November/msg00039.html revolving around filters in lvm.conf, but was not able to properly exploit it, since the PV appears to have been purged of its logical volume, perhaps because my filters weren't restrictive enough ("a|/dev/md2|" matches /dev/md20).  Its possible that if I had been more careful I could have avoided cross-pollution of the new VG metadata onto the lost&found PV.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out *a* way to recover the raid.  Modern LVM systems make backups of the VG configuration pretty often.  You can see a list of your backups and the commands that triggered them using `vgcfgrestore --list` .  I picked the one from before when I did the `vgreduce --removemissing` and found these relevant bits inside it:

```
pv8 {
        id = "SUXIe9-B4xG-Qlbz-5cSd-f1dh-cRQh-vOF4qz"
        device = "unknown device"       # Hint only

        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
        flags = ["MISSING"]
        dev_size = 1048312832   # 499.875 Gigabytes
        pe_start = 2048
        pe_count = 127967       # 499.871 Gigabytes
}
```

and

```
homes18 {
        id = "d7yt43-PMTv-XnsH-qAff-3d5A-ilB6-eQB0Jy"
        status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
        flags = []
        segment_count = 1

        segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 89600    # 350 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1        # linear

                stripes = [
                        "pv8", 0
                ]
        }
}
```

So I created a copy of that file and removed `"MISSING"` from the `flags =` .  I also set the `device = "/dev/md2"`, although that probably was not necessary.  I performed a `vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/archive/mg20_synthetic-2015.vg mg20` and now my mg20/homes18 is back and passes an fsck.

To be honest, I'm not really satisfied with this as an answer.  It's a little bit of overkill to restore the ENTIRE configuration.

I think a real answer might involve `lvcreate -Z n`, but I'm too lazy to perform the necessary experiments to verify this.